# Unable to retrieve image from SQLite. SKImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Tags: android, image, sqlite, display

Currently I'm developing an app which involves capture, save and retrieve image from SQLite. I managed to capture and save image into SQLite. However, I cannot retrieve the image back. I have converted the image into byte array before saved it inside SQLite. This is my coding:

Database.java

```
public String displayImageBendaOne(String rowId){
    SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, BacaHelper.TABLE_NAME_BENDA, new String[] {BacaHelper.UID,
                    BacaHelper.BENDA, BacaHelper.BENDA_IMAGE, BacaHelper.BENDA_ID}, BacaHelper.BENDA_ID + "==" + rowId, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    StringBuffer buffer= new StringBuffer();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        {
            //byte[] bImageOne=cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(BacaHelper.BENDA_IMAGE));
            byte[] bImageOne = cursor.getBlob(1);
            buffer.append(bImageOne);
        }
    }
    db.close();
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Baca.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.benda_read);
        bacaHelper= new BacaDatabaseAdapter(this);
        bIOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageOne);

        passVar = getIntent().getStringExtra(benda.ID_EXTRA);
        String bendaIOne = bacaHelper.displayImageBendaOne(passVar);
        Log.e("Byte[] ", bendaIOne);

        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bendaIOne.getBytes());
        theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        imageStream.reset();
        bIOne.setImageBitmap(theImage);
    }
```

There are no syntax error at the moment but when I run my apps, the image does not appear. In LogCat showed SKImageDecoder:: Factory returned null. What is the meaning of this statement? There is something about above coding I cannot figure out. I have decided to convert from image to byte array to string to byte array to image. Which is a long process because I don't know how to directly retrieve value of byte array from database. Can anyone point out what I should do? Thanks in advanced.

Updated.

This is the class where I converted image into byte array and save inside database.

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_REQUEST:

                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                String bendaTambah=benda.getText().toString();

                if (extras != null) {
                    Bitmap yourImage = extras.getParcelable("data");
                    // convert bitmap to byte
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
                    Log.e("output before conversion", imageInByte.toString());
                    // Inserting Contacts
                    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                    bacaHelper.addContact(new BendaCall(bendaTambah, imageInByte, passVar));
                    Intent i = new Intent(benda.this,
                            benda.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();

                }
                break;
            case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:
                Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
                String bendaTambah2=benda.getText().toString();

                if (extras2 != null) {
                    Bitmap yourImage = extras2.getParcelable("data");
                    // convert bitmap to byte
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
                    Log.e("output before conversion", imageInByte.toString());
                    // Inserting Contacts
                    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                    bacaHelper.addContact(new BendaCall(bendaTambah2, imageInByte, passVar));
                    Intent i = new Intent(benda.this,
                            benda.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                } else{
                   Message.message(this, "Tidak berjaya menambah gambar ");
                }

                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this code

Modify your displayImageBendaOne method like

```
public Bitmap displayImageBendaOne(String rowId){
SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(true, BacaHelper.TABLE_NAME_BENDA, new String[] {BacaHelper.UID,
                BacaHelper.BENDA, BacaHelper.BENDA_IMAGE, BacaHelper.BENDA_ID}, BacaHelper.BENDA_ID + "==" + rowId, null,
        null, null, null, null);
//StringBuffer buffer= new StringBuffer();
Bitmap bm=null;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    {
        //byte[] bImageOne=cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(BacaHelper.BENDA_IMAGE));
        byte[] bImageOne = cursor.getBlob(1);

         bm=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bImageOne , 0, bImageOne.length);
       // buffer.append(bImageOne);
    }
}
db.close();
return bm;
```

}

In your onCreate method instead of

```
  String bendaIOne = bacaHelper.displayImageBendaOne(passVar);
    Log.e("Byte[] ", bendaIOne);

    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bendaIOne.getBytes());
    theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    imageStream.reset();
    bIOne.setImageBitmap(theImage);
```

Use this

```
Bitmap image=bacaHelper.displayImageBendaOne(passVar);
bIOne.setImageBitmap(image);
```

code to open camera

```
 if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                  {
                     // String s=sharedPreferences.getString("source", "");
                        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
                        path1=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg";
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(AddItem.this);
                      File file =new File(contextWrapper.getDir("Inventory", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)+File.separator + "image.jpg");
                      path1=contextWrapper.getDir("Inventory", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)+File.separator + "image.jpg";
                      Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                    //  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                  }
```

code to get image from camera

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == AddItem.this.RESULT_OK) 
        {
            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) 
         {//if image is captured from camera
   //    count++;
                 Bitmap bitmap;
                 String fname;
            if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
              {
                 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
                    BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),btmapOptions);
                      bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 500, 500);
                      fname="image.jpg";

                     try {
                         ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(file.getAbsolutePath()); 
                         int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 
                                             ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                         int rotate = 0;
                            switch(orientation) {
                               case  ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                                    rotate-=90;break;
                               case  ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                                    rotate-=90;break;
                               case  ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                                    rotate-=90;break;
                               }
                                // Log.d("Fragment", "EXIF info for file " + name1 + ": " + rotate);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                             //   Log.d("Fragment", "Could not get EXIF info for file " + name1 + ": " + e);
                            }
                 //    viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
              }
            else
            {
                  ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(AddItem.this);
                  File file =new File(contextWrapper.getDir("Inventory", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)+File.separator + "image.jpg");
                // File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
                    BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),btmapOptions);
                      bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 500, 500);
                      fname="image.jpg";
                   //  viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            //add to database


            addlabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Inventory inv= new Inventory(bitmap,fname,name,date);
            DbHelper.open();
            long count=DbHelper.insertInvDetails(inv);
            //Toast.makeText(AddItem.this, count+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            DbHelper.close();

    }

        }

    }
```

code to obtain a full size image

```
 public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
    { // BEST QUALITY MATCH

        //First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize, Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight) 
        {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        }
        int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

        if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) 
        {
            //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }

        options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    }
```

Utility class use to converting image to byte array and decoding it back to bimap

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;

public class Utility {
// convert from bitmap to byte array
public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);

    return stream.toByteArray();
}

// convert from byte array to bitmap
public static Bitmap getPhoto(byte[] image) {
    Log.i("", image.toString());
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}
```

}

Database code to insert data

```
public long insertInvDetails(Inventory invent) {
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(EMP_PHOTO, Utility.getBytes(invent.getBitmap()));
    cv.put(EMP_NAME, invent.getName());
    cv.put(EMP_PNAME, invent.getPersonName());
    cv.put(EMP_Date, invent.getDate());
    cv.put("IsDeleted", 0);
    long count=mDb.insert(INVENTORY_TABLE, null, cv);
    return count;
}
```

**UPDATE**

code to retrieve data

```
public List<Inventory> getSelectedContacts() {
    List<Inventory> invlist = new ArrayList<Inventory>();
    // Select All Query
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mDb.query(true, INVENTORY_TABLE, new String[] {EMP_ID, EMP_PHOTO,
            EMP_NAME, EMP_PNAME,EMP_Date }, "IsDeleted=1", null, null, null, null, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Inventory inv = new Inventory();
            inv.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(EMP_PHOTO));
            inv.setBitmap(Utility.getPhoto(blob));
            inv.setName(cursor.getString(2));
            inv.setPersonName(cursor.getString(3));
            inv.setDate(cursor.getString(4));
            // Adding contact to list
            invlist.add(inv);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    mDb.close();
    // return contact list
    return invlist;

}
```

Code to call getSelectedContactsand display image in linearlayout

```
    List<Inventory> select_contacts = db.getSelectedContacts();
    LinearLayout newll=new LinearLayout(MainPage.this);
    newll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    for (Inventory cn : select_contacts) {

     ImageView myImage = new ImageView(MainPage.this);
      myImage.setImageBitmap(cn.getBitmap());
     newll.addView(myImage);

    }
    //add newll to your parent view
```

Here is my inventory class for holding values

```
package com.graficali.inventorysystem;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Inventory {
private Bitmap bmp;
private String filename;
private String personname;
 String created_at;
private int id;

public Inventory()
{

}
public Inventory(Bitmap b, String n, String pn, String created_at) {
    bmp = b;
    filename = n;
    personname = pn;
    this.created_at=created_at;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bmp;
}

public String getName() {
    return filename;
}
public String getDate() {
    return this.created_at;
}

public int getID() {
    return this.id;
}
public String getPersonName() {
    return personname;
}
public void setBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
    this.bmp=bmp;
}

public void setName(String filename) {
     this.filename=filename;
}

public void setID(int id) {
     this.id=id;
}

public void setPersonName(String personname)
{

    this.personname=personname;
}
public void setDate(String created_at) {
    this.created_at = created_at;
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for the quick respond. I have tried your code but unfortunately no miracle happened. The logcat still showed SKImageDecoder::Factory returned null.

Comment: @hayatul husna This error usually comes when you try to decode an invalid byte string. Just check you are inserting right byte array string in database at the time of saving image.

Comment: I have updated my question with a class where I converted image into byte array. Is there any difference between byte string and byte array string? The value of byte array inside database is like this : [B@543573b4 . Is it correct?

Comment: I used the same code. Instead of yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); I use bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream); It is working fine in my case.

Comment: I have followed your code but I'm still not able to display the image. Is it normal the value of byte array inside the database keeps changing? When I save inside the database the value is : [B@5432bf94 and then when i retrieve it the value become : [B@5435b848

Comment: I have updated my answer. I have given you all the code required for inserting and retrieving images to sqlite db for reference. It is working fine in my case. change it according to your requirement.

Comment: I have modified my coding based on yours. Can I ask one more favor from you? Can you show me your coding of how you call retriveEmpDetails() and display the image in .java?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope this will help you if you still facing a problem to display the image.

Comment: SKImageDecoder::Factory returned null error have gone but the image still does not appear. Is it something to do with the emulator? Because inside Logcat showed EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented.

Comment: Okay. Don't bother to reply my question above. Finally I did it! The image appear now. Thanks to you. Thank you very much. Really appreciate your help. =D